# RocketMQLog:WARN Please initialize the logger system properly?

Tags: rocketmq

run the Producer , show this:
`RocketMQLog:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (io.netty.util.internal.InternalThreadLocalMap). RocketMQLog:WARN Please initialize the logger system properly.`

How to configure ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

will be fixed in RocketMQ4.9.4, or you fix by this pr
https://github.com/apache/rocketmq/pull/4001